# Why does my ckEditor not save the ' character properly?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, decode

The ckEitor does not save the single inverted comma in my database. All other characters and special characters all saving except the single inverted comma.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue to me. Have all documents the same encoding and has your HTML a correct `<meta charset="...">`?

Answer (score 1):

do this before saving to DB

```
$formattedContent = htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```

and when showing

```
html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES);
```

This worked fine on mine.

[Read what is `<meta charset=“utf-8”>?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869743/what-is-meta-charset-utf-8)